# FirebaseUI crashes when attempting to show auth picker

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase and FirebaseUI in my project, and on a regular basis I'm presented with the same crash when trying to log in. The user taps the `Log in` button and then the authentication picker is supposed to be shown, from where the user can log in with either Facebook/Google or email/password. What happens, though, is that it crashes with *no* error message whatsoever except for marking the following line:

```
struct FIRAuthLogin {
    private let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    private var viewController: UIViewController!

    init(delegate: FIRCustomAuthDelegate, viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController

        authUI?.delegate = delegate
        authUI?.providers = [FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIFacebookAuth()]
    }

    func present(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        // Exception on the line below!
        let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()

        self.viewController.present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Even though there is an exception in the line `let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()`, `authViewController` is *not* `nil`.

Below is an image from the stack trace (in the issue navigator):

[image]

The problem is that I'm *only* overriding the `FUIPasswordSignUpViewController`, so I'm a bit confused.

Whenever this happens, I usually just remove CocoaPods from my project and integrates it again. Then it would work correctly, but as I've done this multiple times now, and the error persist, there must an underlying error. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the error with the FirebaseUI GitHub code, so I'm guessing the error is on my end. That's why I'm asking here instead of in the FirebaseUI-iOS GitHub repository.

Comment: Try to make your code safer, like adding `if let` for your `authViewController`. I'm guessing that that won't happen in production??? I hope not. I got that theory because you mentioned about re-installing the framework via Cocoapods. Try to reproduce that crash when testing your app via TestFlight.

Comment: I'm testing via TestFlight, and it's working correctly. As I said, `authViewController` isn't `nil`. I get the same exception when using `if let`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *finally* fixed. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/361#event-1312975920) in the FirebaseUI iOS repository, and after sending my project to one of the Google engineers, he solved it:

> Looks like you're running into [CocoaPods/CocoaPods#6936](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6936). Setting the build system to use the standard (not the new build system preview), deleting DerivedData, and rebuilding fixes the issue.
>
> For the time being you'll have to not use the new build system.